# What permissions does HAS_DBACCESS check?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions

I assume that

```
SELECT HAS_DBACCESS('database name')
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('database name', 'DATABASE', 'permission name')
```

for some permission (or set of permissions, the results of which need anding together).

Is this assumption correct? If so what are the permissions?

Answer (score 3):

[HAS_DBACCESS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/has-dbaccess-transact-sql) returns 1 if:

- the current Login / User has the ability to access the DB (whether through an Instance-level permission, or by having a User in that DB that is mapped to the current Login)
- the DB is *not* `OFFLINE` or `SUSPECT`
- the DB is in

  - `MULTI_USER` mode, or
  - `SINGLE_USER` mode and the current Login / User is that single user
  - `RESTRICTED_USER` mode and the current Login / User is either a member of the `dbcreator` or `sysadmin` fixed server roles, or is a member of the `db_owner` fixed database role

As far as my testing (with a low-privileged Login / User) shows, this appears to be equivalent to the following:

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('{database_name}', 'DATABASE', 'ANY');
```

I tried other permissions besides `ANY` (i.e. `AUTHENTICATE` and `CONNECT`) and they did not always match `HAS_DBACCESS`.